# AIR iOS load external swf ABC - almost succeeded

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air, flash

I have an entire day of searching and testing behind me and I officialy think it's impossible. Yet there is left to share what I've accomplished and ask for any sugestions.

So I'm working on Flash Builder 4.7, AIR SDK 3.5 and iPad 3 iOS 6.0.1.
What I want is to have an ad-hoc application to load a swf file containing actionscript and add it to stage. I started by testing the application in debug mode on device connected by usb. Everything works well. Then I compiled an ad-hoc release build, which did not work that well. Graphics was added to stage but actionscript didn't run. I've started to search the web and found out that it was possible to load swf's packed in ipa that could run actionscript, but it is no more, though there was [a link to the download page](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/) of that SDK version under "Where can I get the build?"

It didn't work. I included the second swf in export package contents. Did I do it wrong?
Anyway even if it worked what I actually need is to be able to download a swf from a server, save it in storage directory and then load it to the main application.

Is there maybe a way to tell iOS that the application it's running is a debug version (that's actually working), but it shouldn't display the popup with information about connecting to a debugger and it actually should run fast like a legit release build?

Comment: Hmm... When debugging, do you get a security sandbox violation error?  Are you getting the target swf from a remote server, or from your file system?  It could be domain issues

Comment: When debugging I can load swf from a server and from file system. It works both ways and there's no error. In release build I set loaded swf's domain to current domain.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to load external SWFs in iOS Adobe AIR, unless they have been precompiled to native code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not load any code from any server to execute it. Apple forbids it. The only code that can be loaded from outside and executed on iOS is JavaScript within the built in WebKit browser (using UIWebView or in case of Air - StageWebView).

[As of air 3.6](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air3-6_flashplayer11-6_releasenotes.pdf) (which is still in beta) you can package additional swfs with your application for later loading with Loader class, but this feature is still severely limited compared to normal web swf loading - you are only allowed to load code to the same ApplicationDomain your application uses and you can not unload anything so it is just easier to link all the code to one swf statically using swc libraries for example and not bother with loading anything.

Comment: We already try that (to load all SWF into the same ApplicationDomain) and it didn't work. The SWF files were loaded without erros, but when we call `applicationDomain.hasDefinition(name)`, `false` is always returned for names that we know (and see in Flash Professional CS5.5) exists, and `applicationDomain.getDefinition(name)` throws an Error (because it doesn't have the name).

Comment: That is what happens when using the air 3.5 sdk or when loading external swfs using 3.6 sdk. The way it works in 3.6 is the compiler basically packages all the bytecode from every additional swf into main application swf when you package the application. So even in 3.6 no code actually gets loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

We've found that loading SWFs with ABC code in iOS can be done without any problem with Flash Builder 4.7 and AIR 3.6 SDK. At this time Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 comes with AIR 3.5 SDK, so you can download the last SDK version from [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/air/) and install it into your Adobe Flash Builder **sdks** folder.

Comment: Could you share more infos about this please?

Comment: I'd like to know more about this too, please, can you share some information?

Comment: And what exactly "can be done"? 
Loading external SWFs with ABC code on IOS, as the question states?

Comment: I've share all the information. The only thing we had to do was to upgrade our AIR SDK version and it worked.